# Crowd/Pedestrian Simulator in ROS?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
Does anyone know (or is using) a crowd/pedestrian simulator integrated with ROS?
My intention is to have a robot navigating among a realistic group of people.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59360/crowd/pedestrian-simulator-in-ros?/) by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4402 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-10-09**:
hi, Dear Stein, have you got answer? which simulator for crowd/pedestrian are you using? Thank you!

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-10-23**:
hi, I had to develop my own, based on Helbing Social Forces model, together with Stage.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-10-23**:
hi, Have you got some progress? I am beginning to develop a simulator based on Stage. I also found an opensource http://pedsim.silmaril.org/. If you are developing a simulator based on Stage. I am interested to join your project. Thank you

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-10-23**:
I just found an implementation of PedSim for ROS, check the answer bellow. I believe it is much more flexible then my implementation in Stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an implementation of [PedSim](http://pedsim.silmaril.org/) for ROS: https://github.com/srl-freiburg/pedsim_ros

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3